# Is it useful to destroy infected village?

Tags: they-are-billions

Some zombies regulary goes out the village, but not much if you don't disturb it.

Destroying a village requires a lot of effort. At the time when you can do it, the resource left in ruins are not so important.

Do you think it's important to destroy infected villages or do you do it only in some special cases ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is usefull to destroy Infected Village for three reasons:

1. Dropped resources.
2. Units experience.
3. Every non-killed zombie will join the final wave. All zombies from all buildings in  infected villages are included. If you want to make final wave easier, you need to get rid of as many zombies on the map as possible, ideally all of them.